# Ignite, Spark - Deserializing the [B value from sql query result to HashMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

Query I'm using to create table,

```
CREATE TABLE counts_tbl ( id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, counts BINARY ) WITH
\"template=partitioned\""
```

Apache spark User Defined function -

```
val countListUdf = udf((countList: WrappedArray[String]) => {
        var countMap: HashMap[String, Long] = HashMap.empty[String, Long]
        countList.foreach(c => {
            if (countMap.contains(c)) {
                countMap(c) = requestCountMap(c) + 1
            } else {
                countMap(c) = 1
            }
        })
        countMap
    })
```

Storing the dataframe to apache ignite -

```
df.
agg(
  requestListUdf(collect_list("count")).as("counts")
).
withColumn("id", udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)).
write.
     format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE).
      option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE,
"/usr/local/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite.xml").
      option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE, "counts_tbl").
      option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS,
"id").
      option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS,
"template=replicated").
      mode(SaveMode.Append).
      save()
```

Warning while saving dataframe -

WARN  BinaryContext:576 - Class
"scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy" cannot be serialized
using BinaryMarshaller because it either implements Externalizable interface
or have writeObject/readObject methods. OptimizedMarshaller will be used
instead and class instances will be deserialized on the server. Please
ensure that all nodes have this class in classpath. To enable binary
serialization either implement Binarylizable interface or set explicit
serializer using BinaryTypeConfiguration.setSerializer() method.

Querying the table-

```
var queryResult = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * FROM
counts_tbl")).getAll();
```

Result Set -

```
java.util.List[java.util.List[_]] = [[012415a4-9f12-454b-b800-098fac56842f,
[B@1600e52d], [046845b4-96f3-46e0-93fc-d8735c00a8f6, [B@16bb3fc]]
```

Could you please guide me to deserialize counts field in result set?

And also whats the right way to read/write a dataframe with hashmap?

Methods I've tried to deserialize:

1. Using ObjectInputStream

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
var biValue = resultSet(0)(1).asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
var ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(biValue))

Error - 
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FE920800
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
  ... 55 elided
```

2. Using OptimizedMarshaller

```
import org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
var marshaller = new OptimizedMarshaller
var emptyMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Long]
var biValue = resultSet(0)(1).asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]
marshaller.unmarshal(biValue, emptyMap.getClass.getClassLoader())

Error - 
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4534b60d
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal0(OptimizedMarshaller.java:266)
  at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
  ... 55 elided
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize this map into JSON and then store it as `VARCHAR`.

Alternatively, you can go the [`indexedTypes`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/indexes) route, where you can store objects of arbitrary composition, they will not be available with JDBC, but with `SqlFieldsQuery` they would. However, I'm not sure how this will work with Spark.

Comment: size of that map object is around 1GB. Is it optimal/possible to store in VARCHAR?

Comment: If side of that map is around 1GB, it is equally unoptimal to store it in any kind of column equally. Maybe you can split this map up so that it will be a cache instead? Now, 1GB of cache is not much.